# Maximum amount of transacations in waiting for publish State

Tags: web8.5, publishing, publishtransaction, renderer

I came across a situation where if I have more than 500.000 transactions in the `"Waiting for publish"` state, then publisher treads get messed up. I am guessing this is because the `"QUEUE_MESSAGES"` table gets too big, and it takes too much time to process `"PUBLISH_QUEUE"` table that the publisher service is just not performing.

I know that SDL provides some guidance of about a few thousand items, but I was wondering, how much can I push the limit of items in the queue?

Any experiences?